# Scene rendering by accounting for camera distortion parameters

Tags: rendering, camera

I am working on a software package to generate synthetic images of the Moon (that will be compared to real imagery from spacecraft, *e.g.*, the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter).

I have been able to load a mesh of the Moon, and set up a rendering pipeline based on Blender Cycles. However, I am experiencing issues in accounting for camera distortion parameters. **Is it possible to render an image by accounting for the distortion parameters of the camera lens?**

Thank you!

Comment: What issues are you encountering? Please be more specific.